# MySQL: Select unique values from comma separated list

Tags: mysql, unique

I have a list of integers that contains duplicate values, such as `1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6`. Is there a way, using MySQL, to `SELECT` a list of unique values (`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` in this case)?

I realize it can be done by creating and inserting into a temporary table:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (value INT);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES (1), (2), (2), (3), (3), (4), (5), (6);
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT value) FROM temp;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp;
ROLLBACK;
```

but is there a way that does not require a temporary table?

The list of integers is not coming from another MySQL table; pretend it is hard-coded.

Comment: You use simply distinct in select

Comment: is the initial *list of integers* just a string?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yeah

Comment: Does a single field has "1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6" or these are in separate rows? If there are separate rows, used DISTINCT. If its a single row then let us know, we will try to solve it

Comment: Is this data, the comma delimited string of integers, already in a field in mysql, or is your plan to send mysql the string and have it return back distinct?

Comment: @JNevill The latter

Comment: This feels very much like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). IF the data set is very large, which has led you to using mysql to solve it, then a temp table seems perfectly reasonable. If the data is small, then perhaps mysql isn't the best option for whatever platform you are sending this from.

Comment: Use this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows applying a distinct

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm afraid I don't see the correlation. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: "split values to multiple rows" you have a list of values (in your case will not be a column but a fixed value) and you want to select those values as rows distinct. The link I provided do exactly that only thing you need is to add the distinct after the split.